# Python : How to open a tkinter message in front of the Spyder IDE window?

Tags: windows, tkinter, spyder

I want to display a messagebox (tkinter package) during a python program executed from Spyder IDE (version 5.1.5 on Windows10). But the Spyder window stays in front of the tkinter one and I can't press on "Enter" key to select "Ok" without clicking on the window before (Yes, I like the shortcut keys !).

We can take this code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo('Information', "It's all right !")
```

There are many articles with explanation to put one tkinter window on the top level of another one, but not in front of the Spyder IDE. Maybe it's because I don't know how to formulate my request.

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you !

Comment: I have neve used Spyder, however in my experience I have never had this issue.  When using a `messagebox` it should not only be on top of all other window but it should also hold `focus` until you satisfy an event. This is the default behavior of a `messagebox`.  Have you tried to run your code in just the python native IDE to see if it behaves the same?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Rory ! I have the same issue with `filedialog.askdirectory`. From the Anaconda prompt, it's all right. But, by the same way, I can no more use global variable (my script acquires data from accelerometer, and I repeat it several times, but I would like save some parameters).

Answer (score 5):

The trick should be to use the Window Manager (wm) attributes in Tkinter, in particular the following:

```
win.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
```

where -topmost is an option to make the window always be on top of all the other windows.
So, I provide you a code that should solve your issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

win=tk.Tk()
win.withdraw()

# Makes the window topmost
win.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)

messagebox.showinfo('Information', "It's all right !")
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea ! Off the top of my head, I tried it. But I managed to get around the problem by doing something else. I think I did not use tkinter properly.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Works in Windows11